# Can 'so that' be used to express apposition?

Tags: grammar

Once I saw a clause : "The whole purpose of the special rules around arrays is so that you can use a pointer to an array element as though it were an array" in a reply posted on Stack Overflow.
I have seen usages like 'the purpose of it is that ~' or 'the purpose of it is such that', but not one like 'the purpose of it is so that'.
Is it gramatically correct to use 'so that' like such?

Comment: Pleonastic but grammatical IMO. *That* may be preferable; *such that* does not mean the same thing - what comes next does not define the purpose but is an implication or consequence of the purpose being what it is. It's much the same as *the reason is because* vs *the reason is that* vs *the reason is such that*.

Comment: It has nothing to do with apposition, which consists of noun phrases as modifiers, as in "the opera Carmen", "my wife Lucy" etc. In your example  the expression "so that you can use a pointer to an array element as though it were an array" is a purpose complement.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment BillJ wrote:

> It has nothing to do with apposition, which consists of noun phrases as modifiers, as in "the opera Carmen", "my wife Lucy" etc. In your example  the expression "so that you can use a pointer to an array element as though it were an array" is a purpose complement.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment Minty wrote:

> Pleonastic but grammatical IMO. *That* may be preferable; *such that* does not mean the same thing - what comes next does not define the purpose but is an implication or consequence of the purpose being what it is. It's much the same as *the reason is because* vs *the reason is that* vs *the reason is such that*.